# What is the use of target namespace and SOAP endpoint in a SOAP request using savon gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, soap, savon

What is the use of  target namespace and SOAP endpoint and where to get these in a SOAP request using savon gem?

I'm using [savon](http://savonrb.com/version2/) gem to send a soap request. 
From the documentation it says that:

```
In case your service doesn't have a WSDL,then Savon needs to know about the SOAP endpoint and target namespace of your service.

client = Savon.client do
  endpoint "http://example.com"
  namespace "http://v1.example.com"
end
```

It is not quite clear from where I will get  SOAP endpoint and target namespace details.

It will be great if you can explain in reference with this document:

http://service.smartadserver.com/v29/service.asmx?op=AddInsertion

Answer (score 1):

You must add correctly URL to wsdl file:

```
client = Savon.client(
  :wsdl => 'http://service.smartadserver.com/v29/service.asmx?wsdl'
)
```